# password protect folder with .htaccess not working after login once

Tags: php, .htaccess, passwords

First time *.htaccess* password protected folder working well.

But when I enter second time into *.htaccess password protected folder* then *I can enter* directly .htaccess password  protected folder *without any protection*, that *means .htaccess password protected not working* for second or more time enter into password protected folder.

I need .htaccess password protected system for every time enter into .htaccess password protected folder.

That means, I want to enter every time into .htaccess password protected folder by login.

Comment: This is most likely because you already have a valid session. Try to clear your browsers cache, removing any logins and then access the folder again.

Comment: it's not really a session, you are sending again and again the user:password@blabla or the Authentication: Basic blabla (I dunno it depends on the implementation, I think apache is using the first).

I think if you want to have a nice login you should do it by php and in it you should handle the basic auth